# Chimney with adjacent brick shafts into attic

Tags: insulation, fireplace, chimney

I have dual fireplaces back-to-back on either side of a wall. They are separate fireplaces; there is clearly a solid barrier at the back of each fireplace. They and the whole chimney are brick. We have had both sides serviced and both work fine. One is set up for gas and the other for gas or wood.

I'm insulating my attic and found brick shafts adjacent to the chimney on the left and the right of the chimney proper. They are clearly part of the chimney construction. One is fairly clear but the other has trash insulation filling it up about 1/2 way.

What are these things and is it important that I clean out the trashy one?

photo of right side
[image: photo of right side]
photo of chimney coming up through ceiling
[image: photo of chimney coming up through ceiling]
photo of shaft on left side
[image: photo of shaft on left side]

Comment: they could be ducts for make-up air to the fires  or they could just be decorative

Comment: I was thinking (heatAlator not sure of spelling) heat channels where the chimney itself has air channels that help heat the air , these were expensive at the time but over the life pay for themselves many times over if used for heating.  If you have bricks with airspace’s on the face of the chimney this would indicate they were used or designed for heating

Comment: I could see it being a shaft for make up air - air drawn through it would be warmed by the warm chimney bricks. Can you drop a mirror or camera into the one with out the shaft too look for evidence of a vent or an old opening in the bricks? - Maybe it was covered up in a previous remodel

Comment: @Jon - I should have posted good pictures in my initial post. Now I'm at the stage in putting in blown-in insulation that I have covered the openings with a 1/4" hardware cloth so that I at least leave them in their present state.